# FastAPI Query with dataclass not working with alias

Tags: python-3.x, alias, fastapi, pydantic, python-dataclasses

the following FastAPI code is producing unexpected behaviour to me:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query
from typing import Optional
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


app = FastAPI()

@dataclass
class Catz:
    qqq: Optional[str] = Query(None, alias="q")

@app.get("/productz/")
def search_products(query: Catz = Depends(Catz)  ):
    products = [{"name": "Computer"}, {"name": "HDD"}]
    if not query.qqq:
        query.qqq = ""
    return {"query": query, "results": [product for product in products if query.qqq in product["name"]]}


@dataclass
class Cats:
    qqq: Optional[str] = Query(None )

@app.get("/products/")
def search_products(query: Cats = Depends(Cats)  ):
    products = [{"name": "Computer"}, {"name": "HDD"}]
    if not query.qqq:
        query.qqq = ""
    return {"query": query, "results": [product for product in products if query.qqq in product["name"]]}




if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", port=11978, log_level="info", reload=True)
```

when I use the service via curl, I get the following outputs:

1. the expected behaviour with the endpoint /products/ that has no aliases

```
>> curl -X 'GET'  'http://localhost:11978/products/?qqq=H'  -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'api-version: 1.0' ; echo
{"query":{"qqq":"H"},"results":[{"name":"HDD"}]}
```

2. not the expected behaviour with the endpoint /productz/ that has no aliases (regardless of me using a query parameter with its own name or with the alias I have in the code)

```
>> curl -X 'GET'  'http://localhost:11978/productz/?qqq=H'  -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'api-version: 1.0' ; echo
{"query":{"qqq":""},"results":[{"name":"Computer"},{"name":"HDD"}]}

>> curl -X 'GET'  'http://localhost:11978/productz/?q=H'  -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'api-version: 1.0' ; echo
{"query":{"qqq":""},"results":[{"name":"Computer"},{"name":"HDD"}]}
```

any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not import `dataclass` from `pydantic.dataclasses` - it should be [imported from Python's own built-in `dataclasses` module](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/dataclasses/?h=dataclass#using-dataclasses):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


app = FastAPI()


@dataclass
class Catz:
    qqq: Optional[str] = Query(None, alias="q")

    
@app.get("/productz/")
def search_products(query: Catz = Depends()):
    products = [{"name": "Computer"}, {"name": "HDD"}]
    if not query.qqq:
        query.qqq = ""
    return {"query": query, "results": [product for product in products if query]}
```

Outputs for `/productz?q=123`:

```json
{"query":{"qqq":"123"},"results":[{"name":"Computer"},{"name":"HDD"}]}
```

Comment: Can I ask what's the difference? --I had other behaviours breaking by not importing from pydantic, I can't reproduce the issue right now, but I could do an "import as" and have them both imported.
\\At any rate, Thanks for the hint, I'll work on it tomorrow (late evening here) and mark this answered!

Comment: According with the link you posted (which was exactly my case): <<In some cases, you might still have to use Pydantic's version of dataclasses. For example, if you have errors with the automatically generated API documentation.>> . --the solution here was to use both imported separately, as in this example from pydantic's documentation: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/#inherit-from-stdlib-dataclasses

Comment: Yeah, sounds like its a bug, since it almost works; might want to report it on the FastAPI bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

You can append to @dataclass-decorator the argument  `config={'extra': 'allow'}`, so, your code will be looks like

```
@dataclass(config={'extra': 'allow'})
class Catz:
   qqq: Optional[str] = Query(None, alias="q")
```

But you should keep in mind what if you pass parameter `qqq` instead `q` in the query — it will return a validation error.